# Get message from mssql query in python

Tags: python, sql-server

I need get info about open transaction in MSSQL. If I get info in cmd line

```
sqlcmd -S serv1 -Q "DBCC opentran"
```

I get:

```
  Oldest active transaction:
         SPID (server process ID): 661
         UID (user ID) : -1
         Name          : INSERT
         LSN           : (6611914:123819:1)
         Start time    : Oct  2 2015  9:43:18:060AM
         SID           : 0x39d6ed27627f5c438e8d8fe2588b3ec6
```

If I try make this in python :

```
import dbcc 
conn=odbc.odbc("Driver={SQL Server};Server=srv1;Trusted_Connection=Yes") 
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('dbcc opentran')
print cursor.fetchall()
```

I get

```
dbi.internalError: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]═No data in
FETCH
```

Because the text it not **result** and the text is the **message**.
Whether there is a simple way of obtaining the text of the message through odbc.
If such way isn't present, what it is necessary to use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can get information from [sysprocesses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881(v=sql.120).aspx):

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) AS DBNAME, 
    (SELECT text FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)) AS SQLSTATEMENT
FROM master..sysprocesses 
WHERE open_tran > 0
```

Or, from [dm_tran_current_transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186327.aspx):

```
SELECT 
    transaction_id
   ,transaction_sequence_num
   ,transaction_is_snapshot
   ,first_snapshot_sequence_num
   ,last_transaction_sequence_num
   ,first_useful_sequence_num
FROM sys.dm_tran_current_transaction;
```

Comment: Whether there is a method to get access to the **message** in odbc or other library ?